# FATAL EXCEPTION: main NoSuchMethodError for VideoView.setOnPreparedListener()

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I am trying to play live video using `VideoView`. In some devices, it is working fine and in some devices, I am getting an error and app gone crash:

**Error**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getPlaybackParams()Landroid/media/PlaybackParams; 
>   in class Landroid/media/MediaPlayer;
>   or its super classes (declaration of 'android.media.MediaPlayer' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar

**My code:**

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // optional need Vitamio 4.0
        try {
            float speed = 0.75f;
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackParams(mediaPlayer.getPlaybackParams().setSpeed(speed));
            playpause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoView.start();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: This question was supposed to show you, that the error is caused, when the code is invoked on system version below 23. And that it is not so simple to control the speed of video on all Android versions and probably you need to use external video players rather than standard Android's `VideoView`.

Comment: please suggest me external video player . in which my video play fine for all versions of android